# Accessing class method vairable in instance method

Tags: python

I have a class that has a classmethod and a instance method..The classmethod creates a class variable cls.name.

I would like to know how to access the class variable cls.name in my instance method - parent_method.

```
class Parent():
        def __init__(self):
            print "Parent initialized"

        @classmethod    
        def resource_setup(cls):
            cls.name = "P"
            print "parent method"

        def parent_method(self):
            print self.name
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta: What `def Parent:`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call that class method in order for the name to come into existence.

BTW, since you're using Python 2 you should explicitly derive your classes from `object`, otherwise you get [old-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/4014959).

Here's a quick demo (running on Python 2.6.6)

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent initialized"

    @classmethod
    def resource_setup(cls):
        cls.name = "P"
        print "parent method"

    def parent_method(self):
        print self.name

Parent.resource_setup()
a = Parent()
a.parent_method()
print a.name
```

**output**

```
parent method
Parent initialized
P
P
```

---

Note that you don't *need* to call `.resource_setup()` via `Parent`, you can also do it using an instance, but I think it's more explicit to call class methods using the class name. The code below uses the same class definition as above, so I won't repeat it.

```
a = Parent()
a.resource_setup()
a.parent_method()

b = Parent()
b.parent_method()
```

**output**

```
Parent initialized
parent method
P
Parent initialized
P
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access class variable from instance after you initialized it in class method.

```
p = Parent()
p.resource_setup()
p.parent_method()
```

Class and instance variables are in different namespaces. When you call attribute the first lookups are in instance dictionary

```
p.__dict__
```

next in class dictionary

```
p.__class__.__dict__
```

and so on in dictionaries from instance class being inherited.